# FileNotFoundException exception on My.Computer.Audio.Play

Tags: vb.net, audio

I'm making a program for recording audio.

Code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Declare Function record Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal lpstrReturnString As String, ByVal uReturnLength As Integer, ByVal hwndCallback As Integer) As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        record("open new Type waveaudio Alias recon", "", 0, 0)
        record("record recon", "", 0, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        record("save recon c:\mic.wav", "", 0, 0)
        record("close recon", "", 0, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        My.Computer.Audio.Play("c:\mic.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Error occurs on line        `My.Computer.Audio.Play("c:\mic.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)`:

> FileNotFoundException was unhandled
>   Please be sure a sound file exists at the specified location.

Comment: Does the file exist at C:\mic.wav

Comment: No, as I read on internet because that code automatic create mic.wav and then play it

Comment: This is code from the previous century.  Behaves like it as well, the C:\ directory is protected by UAC.  So Button2 will not work, you can't find out because you ignore the return value of mciSendString().  Button3 is therefore doomed to fail.  Pick a better directory and a [correct declaration](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm/mciSendString.html) and add the *required* error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

This works For me try it and see

```
Public Class Form1

Private Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal lpstrReturnString As String, ByVal uReturnLength As Integer, ByVal hwndCallback As Integer) As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Button1.Enabled = False

    Button2.Enabled = True

    mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0)

    mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0)

    Label1.Text = "Recording..."

    Label1.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Button1.Enabled = True

    Button2.Enabled = False

    Button3.Enabled = True

    mciSendString("save recsound c:\recsound.wav", "", 0, 0)

    mciSendString("close recsound", "", 0, 0)

    MsgBox("File Created: C:\recsound.wav")

    Label1.Text = "Stopped..."

    Label1.Visible = False

    My.Computer.Audio.Stop()

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Label1.Text = "Playing..."

    Label1.Visible = True

    My.Computer.Audio.Play("c:\recsound.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)

End Sub

End Class
```